# How to compare encrypted strings with random seeds?

Tags: php, encryption, duplicates

I want to store profile details encrypted within a database. However, some details should be unique, and since the encryption algorithm randomizes the seed for each encryption, it's exhaustive to tell whether the value is already stored within the database.

- I could loop through each row and decrypt the necessary column, but that would take too long if the number of rows is large.
- I could store hashes of these (unencrypted) details <s>but that would kill the point of encryption in the first place</s>.

**So, how do I compare an encrypted string (with random seed) with others saved in the database?**

Any help is highly appreciated. Encryption is made with php (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`/`NOFB`), database is MySQL.

**Edit/solution:** Storing the data hashed in addition to the encrypted value seems to be my best solution. That makes validation of unique columns easy enough for me. Thanks to everyone leaving their comments/answers.

Comment: Interesting question, although I don't think there is an answer beyond "store them unencrypted in a separate column"... But we'll see

Comment: I'd use the hash with a user-dependent salt, such as their username. This way, if a profile field for one user is known, another user having the same unhashed value in that field cannot be deduced, since their hash will be different.

Comment: @Pekka yes, let's see...

Comment: @halfer I need to be able to decrypt the values and also compare new posts to every row.

Comment: I should have made it clear that the hash would be stored in addition to your encrypted column, so you can still decrypt. To do a comparison, you can take your plaintext value, and then loop through every row, and add your salt value, hash the result, then compare with the stored hash value. A match in hashes means that the plaintext also matches. Obviously, not great if you have a lot of rows - but you could do it in a stored procedure to speed up the loop.

Comment: "I could store hashes of these (unencrypted) details but that would kill the point of encryption in the first place" - meaning that the information alone that two rows contain the same value (even if the attacker doesnt know the value itself) is too sensitive?

Comment: @VolkerK the uniqueness is to prevent certain duplicate profile values for administrative purposes.

Comment: Ok, but that wasn't my question ;-) You said that storing a hash of the payload data would "kill the point of encryption in the first place". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @VolkerK :) sorry for any misunderstanding. At first, I thought that storing the data both encrypted and hashed would lead to poor security. But I've changed my mind and concluded that a hash algorithm that's suitable for passwords also should be suitable for other sensitive profile data.

Comment: Any secure hash should have the property that it is not reversable. In other words, its compression technique is scrambled in such a way that decompression is impossible. There is one big 'but' however: if you can iterate through all the input values you compare the results. If the profiles are large enough, such a brute force pick and try technique probably don't work, but it might be something to keep in mind. For passwords, you need something like PBKDF2 and a maximum number of tries to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've chosen an algorithm that doesn't provide a capability you now say you need. You need to work out your requirements *before* you choose an algorithm.

Comment: Well, it's not too late to change algorithm, any suggestions?

Comment: Either use the same seed for every password or use two separate tracking schemes, one just to catch duplicates (that doesn't track which user has the password!) and one for authentication (that does).

Comment: The question wasn't regarding passwords, but I see the need for a separate data set for comparison. Thanks.

Comment: @Alajo Oh, I missed that. But yeah, it doesn't matter.